# How to map imports in typescript

Tags: typescript

Let' s suppose in typescript, whenever i write an import statement like this

```
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
```

i would like typescript to actually import this file `./styles.module.scss.json`

The reason is that a json object with mappings of classnames from css modules is generated and saved to this file from an external script. Also typings are generated at `./styles.module.scss.d.ts`.

I don't have webpack nor babel plugins available. Is it possible? I saw that you can specifiy a `paths` configuration in compiler options, but i could not make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used json for unit test stub data.
You just need to [enable the setting in your tsconfig file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule).

e.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have json enabled, this does not really answer my question. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Maybe adding an example of the json file you are trying to import will help us answer your question. Are you asking how to have typescript ignore the typings file?